# PHP fsockopen() painfully slow

Tags: php, performance, fsockopen

I'm using fsockopen() to call a number of connections in a list to see the online status of various ip/host and ports ...

```
<?php
$socket = @fsockopen($row[2], $row[3], $errnum, $errstr, 1);
if ($errnum >= 1) { $status = 'offline'; } else { $status = 'online';}
fclose($socket);
```

if works, I'm not complaining about that, but I have approximately 15 ip/ports that i'm retrieving in a list (php for() command..).  I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?  This way is VERY slow!?! It is taking about 1-2 minutes for the server to come back with a response for all of them..

Update:

```
<?php
$socket = @fsockopen("lounge.local", "80", $errnum, $errstr, 30);
if ($errnum >= 1) { $status = 'offline'; } else { $status = 'online'; }
?>
```

It will display in a list: "ReadyNAS AFP   readynas.local:548   online"

I don't know what more I can tell you?  It just takes forever to load the collection of results...

Comment: Thank you for reducing your example code. However, please consider giving a full example script (that scans `stackoverflow.com` or `example.com` or so). The problem is almost certainly not in the excerpt you posted. Also note that you should not call fclose on if `$socket === false`.

Comment: Thank-you, I have taken it out since uploading this snippet.  Updated with full sample script

Comment: If anyone is interested. I was using `fsockopen("localhost")` and it was brutally slow (~1010 ms). with `fsockopen("127.0.0.1")` it was much quicker (~11 ms).

Answer (score 3):

From my own experience:

This code:

```
$sock=fsockopen('www.site.com', 80);
```

is slower compared to:

```
$sock=fsockopen(gethostbyname('www.site.com'), 80);
```

Tested in PHP 5.4. If doing many connections at the same time one could keep host resolution result and re-use it, to further reduce script time execution, for example:

```
function myfunc_getIP($host) {
   if (isset($GLOBALS['my_cache'][$host])) {
      return $GLOBALS['my_cache'][$host];
   }

   return $GLOBALS['my_cache'][$host]=gethostbyname($host);
}

$sock=fsockopen(myfunc_getIP('www.site.com'), 80);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to "ping" some URL, I would advise doing it with curl, why? you can use curl to send pings in parallel, have a look at this -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php. In a previous project, it was supposed to feed Real Time Data to our server, we used to ping hosts to see if they are alive or not and Curl was the only option that helped us.
Its an advice, may not be a right solution for your problem.

Comment: trying to make this happen, and it's proving to be a bit of a challenge... Will get back to you if I'm still lost :)

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter to `fsockopen()` is the timeout, set this to a low value to make the script complete faster, like this:

```
fsockopen('192.168.1.93', 80, $errNo, $errStr, 0.01)
```

Comment: Thank-you, however this has also failed to make the script go any faster... I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you compared the results of `fsockopen(servername)` versus `fsockopen(ip-address)`? If the timeout parameter does not change a thing, the problem may be in your name server. If fsockopen with an IP address is faster, you'll have to fix your name server, or add the domains to /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Will look into that - thankyou!  it's just running off my mac mini XAMPP server... :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this a bit different. 
Put this hosts in a table in a database something like:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| host | port | status | timestamp |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

And move the status checking part in a cron script that you run it once every 5 minutes or how often you want.
This script will check the host:port and update status and timestamp for each record and in your page you will just do a db query and show the host, its status and when was last checked (something like: 1minute ago, etc...)
This way your page will load fast.

Comment: I will not be logging into this page that often (for the purpose of seeing the status), so I don't want to put any more stress on the server if it's not necessary.. But I will read up on 'cron' and see if it would in fact save some time... Thank-you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

According to the php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), there's a timeout parameter. Try setting it to a lower value.

Edit: To add to Daniel's answer,  nmap might be the best tool to use. Set it up with a cron job to scan and update your records every X minutes. Something like

```
$ for ip in $(seq 6 8); 
do 
     port_open=$(nmap -oG - -p 80 10.1.0.$ip|grep open|wc -l); 
     echo "10.1.0.$ip:$port_open"; 
done

10.1.0.6:1
10.1.0.7:1
10.1.0.8:0
```

Comment: originally it was set at 1, did not do anything, so I put it back to the default of 30...

Comment: Hmm, more debugging might be needed for this. If possible, have a look at the tcp stream using tcpdump/wireshark to see what fsockopen is doing. Is it trying to resend? Is the remote host not responding? Is there a firewall throwing a spanner in the works?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where fsockopen requests were slow, but wget was really snappy. In my case, it was happening because the hostname had both an ipv4 and ipv6 address, but ipv6 was down. So it took 20 or so seconds on each request for the ipv6 to time out.